# Dojo AMD loader executing define callbacks with empty / missing dependencies

Tags: javascript, dojo, dependencies, amd

I'm new to Dojo (1.7) and totally willing to accept I'm being an idiot (I just hope not). I am more comfortable using require.js for AMD but I'm using a 3rd-party (ESRI) mapping API that forces Dojo on me and uses its AMD, meaning I get nasty errors if I try and use require.js as well.

I have `define`d a module with dependencies on Backbone and Underscore (I might ultimately go with Dojo's MVC but I don't think this problem is specific to Backbone so I want to get it figured out). Bizarrely it seems that Dojo is executing the callback within my `define` when the module is loaded, and at this point the dependencies (Underscore and Backbone) are empty objects `{}`. An error occurs within my callback's `return Backbone.View.extend...` because Backbone's `View` property doesn't exist.

I know that Backbone is dependent on Underscore, and so far I have no idea how to ensure Underscore is loaded first without using a hacky-looking `require({async:0},['test1.js','test2.js'...`. However, in this case Underscore is also an empty object, so the `define`'s callback is executed before either dependency is loaded???

**EDIT** I see both Underscore and Backbone HTTP requests and 200 responses in the console before this error occurs, so I assume there are no problems in their references.

Something concrete...

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var dojoConfig = {
        tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,

        packages: [
            {name: 'app', location: '/js'},
            {name: 'lib', location: '/js/lib'}
        ],

        aliases: [
            ['Backbone', 'lib/backbone-0.9.2.min'],
            ['_', 'lib/underscore-1.3.3.min'],
            ['$', 'lib/jquery-1.8.0.min'],

            ['ready', 'dojo/domReady']
        ]
    };

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    require([ 'app/app' ], function(App) {
        App.initialize();
    });

</script>
```

app.js:

```
define(['app/views/main-view'], function(MainView) {

    return {
        initialize : function() {
            new MainView();
        }
    };

});
```

main-view.js:

```
define(['_', 'Backbone', 'ready!'], function(_, Backbone) {

    // *** ERROR THROWN HERE, Backbone = {}, _ = {} ***
    return Backbone.View.extend({

        el: 'main',

        initialise: function() {

            console.log('main view initialising');

            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {

            console.log('main view rendering');
        }

    });
});
```

Can anybody (please) tell me what's going on here? Also any alternate suggestions on loading Underscore before Backbone would be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of dependencies:

```
define(['_', 'Backbone', 'ready!'], function(_, Backbone) { /*...*/});
```

Because your have `ready!` plugin in `_` variable and `_.js` in `Backbone` variable.

**Edit:** You can nest it:

```
define(["_", "require"], function(_, require) {

    require(["Backbone"], function(Backbone) {
        // your code here
    })

})
```

Also, if underscore or Backbone are not AMD modules, local function variables will cover them.

Comment: thanks for your input, but nesting the call to Backbone doesn't change the fact that Underscore is still an empty object when the callback is executed. I dare say Backbone will *still* be an empty object even within this nested require. As per my dojoConfig object both '_' and 'Backbone' are loaded as modules, and even if they weren't they would surely be `undefined`, not `{}` if local variables were overriding the modules' values

Comment: also the nested require approach doesn't allow me to define my own module as a Backbone-based object, as I can't return a view directly from the define callback

Comment: I do not know underscore.js or Backbone.js, but if those files are not defined as AMD, i.e. they start with `define([], function(){ /*factory*/ return Backbone; })`, the AMD loader has no means to assign an object to a local variable.

Comment: In the case you need to wrap non-AMD JS into AMD you can get some inspiration here: http://jasonwyatt.tumblr.com/post/18015760792/google-maps-api-in-an-amd-module-requirejs-dojo

Comment: "also the nested require approach doesn't allow me to define my own module" - you can use `module` or `exports`: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#commonjs-require-exports-and-module

Comment: thanks for your perseverence. Stupidly the AMD wrapping of Backbone and Underscore was the problem. Like I said: "totally willing to accept I'm being an idiot"